# Getting only unique values in postresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique

I need something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE <value in column1 is always unique 
(if ever any value will be noticed more than once, then skip this row)>
```

in postgresql.

So if I have these rows in table:

```
1;"something";"xoxox"
2;"other";"xoxox"
3;"something";"blablabla"
```

And then go with the query, then that should be result:

```
2;"other";"xoxox"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your description says "column1" unique, but your output seems to use column 2

Comment: The first is id, not counted as a column :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `count(*)` as a window function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by col1) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

Alternatively, you can use `not exists` and the `id` column:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.id <> t.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter over `count` without the need of a subquery:

```
SELECT t.col1
FROM t
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Other columns can be added by using an aggregation function like `max`, since there will only be 1 row per value:

```
SELECT t.col1, max(t.col2), max(t.col3)
FROM t
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```